# ROS packages for beaglebone black

Tags: ros, beagleboneblack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was trying to run ROS on multiple machines as described in this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines
One of the machines is my ROS Hydro VM while the other is a beaglebone black with beagle-ros installed. However the beagle doesnt have the necessary packages installed like rospy_tutorials or turtlesim.
How do I install these packages so that I can experiment with ROS' distributed computing features?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193912/ros-packages-for-beaglebone-black/) by [vreg](https://answers.ros.org/users/19867/vreg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a bunch of packages available for BeagleBone Black. See the UbuntuARM installation page: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

You can always install from source for anything that is not available from binary packages: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0